# (VBA/VBA EXCEL) Upload picture and make it as a link/clickable text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have my code that can upload a picture. I want to make it as clickable link. See the attached picture. The country will be the link and when I click it. The picture uploaded will show.

I have my userform for Product name, product code, ref. number , and upload img.
when click add. That will be the output and there is a clickable txt/link to img.

http://imgh.us/CLICKABLE.png

```
Private Sub cmdAttachment_Click() 

Dim fname As String 

 fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:= _ 
"JPG Files(*.jpg),*.jpg", Title:="Select Image To Open") 

 'If you did not click Cancel...
 If fname <> "False" Then 
    Dim pic 

    Set pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fname) 

    With pic 
        .Left = 0 
        .Top = 0 
    End With 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to do the following:

- prompt OpenFilename window - this way you can get the directory,
- next, create button within the cell, where you want to have your link (you will replace link with button),
- then add the code to the button click event, that will load and show the picture.

Hope it helps. Best reagrds!

Comment: But I have this userform http://imgh.us/userform_1.png check it.
When I insert image, i want it to be in a cell whether it is button, clickable text, object. What can you suggest?

This will be the format when I encode a product
|Product Code| Product Name | Ref number| clickable image| 
This will be in a table. That's my plan.

Comment: So, add code to insert button click event that will ask for the directory of the picture, then add the button - you can write code, that will generate button using given directory and place it the cell you want it to be.